# Pivot multiple fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I am trying to aggregate two columns by pivoting them each on a third column (hopefully that's the correct terminology).  I got it working one way, but it seems clunky, so I am wondering if there is a better way.  I posted two other ways that are more readable but don't work.

Demo data:

```
DECLARE @counts TABLE (
    machineID INT,
    workShift INT,
    goodCount INT,
    totalCount INT
);

INSERT INTO @counts
VALUES
    (1, 1, 5, 20),
    (1, 1, 5, 20),
    (1, 2, 10, 20),
    (1, 2, 10, 20),
    (1, 2, 10, 20),
    (2, 1, 50, 200),
    (2, 1, 50, 200),
    (2, 2, 100, 200),
    (2, 2, 100, 200),
    (2, 2, 100, 200);

SELECT *
FROM @counts
ORDER BY machineID, workShift;

result:
machineID   workShift   goodCount   totalCount
1           1           5           20
1           1           5           20
1           2           10          20
1           2           10          20
1           2           10          20
2           1           50          200
2           1           50          200
2           2           100         200
2           2           100         200
2           2           100         200
```

**#1** This works, but makes me feel like I'm over-complicating things:

```
WITH goodTable AS (
    SELECT machineID, [1] AS g1, [2] AS g2
    FROM (SELECT machineID, goodCount, workShift FROM @counts) AS t
    PIVOT (SUM(goodCount) FOR workShift IN ([1], [2])) AS piv
    ),
totalTable AS (
    SELECT machineID, [1] AS t1, [2] AS t2
    FROM (SELECT machineID, totalCount, workShift FROM @counts) AS t
    PIVOT (SUM(totalCount) FOR workShift IN ([1], [2])) AS piv
    )
SELECT g.machineID, g1, t1, g2, t2
FROM goodTable as g
JOIN totalTable as t ON g.machineID = t.machineID
ORDER BY machineID;

result:
machineID   g1      t1      g2      t2
1           10      40      30      60
2           100     400     300     600
```

**#2** I would love to be able to do something like this since it's very readable, but it won't compile.

```
SELECT 
    machineID,
    g.[1] AS g1,
    t.[1] AS t1,
    g.[2] AS g2,
    t.[2] AS t2
FROM @counts
PIVOT (SUM(goodCount) FOR workShift IN ([1], [2])) AS g
PIVOT (SUM(totalCount) FOR workShift IN ([1], [2])) AS t
ORDER BY machineID;

result:
The multi-part identifier "g.1" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "g.2" could not be bound.
```

**#3** This is a workaround that's supposed to work but doesn't.  The extra rows it generates could be fixed via `GROUP BY`, except that the numbers aren't even correct.  I got this idea from here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7db49578-a1ef-4e53-864b-c61c5e1150f7/how-do-i-aggregate-on-more-than-one-column-within-a-pivot?forum=transactsql

```
WITH countsPivotable AS (
    SELECT machineID, goodCount, totalCount,
    workshift AS ws1, 
    workshift + 10 AS ws2
    FROM @counts)
SELECT
    machineID, 
    [1] AS g1,
    [11] AS t1,
    [2] AS g2,
    [12] AS t2
FROM countsPivotable
PIVOT (SUM(goodCount) FOR ws1 IN ([1], [2])) AS piv
PIVOT (SUM(totalCount) FOR ws2 IN ([11], [12])) AS piv
ORDER BY machineID;

result:
machineID   g1      t1      g2      t2
1           NULL    NULL    30      20
1           10      20      NULL    NULL
2           NULL    NULL    300     200
2           100     200     NULL    NULL
```

Could I change something to get #2 or #3 to work?

Are there totally different methods that are better?

Bonus: What if there were more columns to aggregate than in my simple example, like if there were also an errorCounts column too?  Or what if there were more than 2 workShifts?  I'm curious how different solutions scale.

Comment: After re-reading your question,  it is unclear as to your desired output  ... aggregate totalCount or distinct totalCount?

Comment: I'm looking for the sum of `goodCount` for each machine during each shift and the sum of `totalCount` for each machine during each shift.  The result at the bottom of my solution #1 shows what I am looking for.

Comment: Reverted back to my original answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could skip the `pivot()` and use the old style pivot like this:

rextester: http://rextester.com/HXUE97581

```
select 
    MachineId
  , Good_1  = sum(case when workshift = 1 then goodcount else 0 end)
  , Total_1 = sum(case when workshift = 1 then totalcount else 0 end)
  , Good_2  = sum(case when workshift = 2 then goodcount else 0 end)
  , Total_2 = sum(case when workshift = 2 then totalcount else 0 end)
  from @counts
  group by MachineId
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **dynamic** version.  As you can see the `Cross Apply` will unpivot your data

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(concat('g',[workShift]))+',' + QuoteName(concat('t',[workShift])) From Yourtable  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
Select [machineID],' + @SQL + '
From (
        Select A.machineID
              ,B.*
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply (
                    Values (concat(''g'',A.workShift),A.goodCount)
                          ,(concat(''t'',A.workShift),A.totalCount)
               ) B (Item,Value)
     ) A
 Pivot (sum(Value) For [Item] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

```
machineID   g1  t1  g2  t2
1           10  40  30  60
2           100 400 300 600
```

If it help with the visualization, the `CROSS APPLY` generates the following:

[image]

And the Generated SQL looks like this:

```
Select [machineID],[g1],[t1],[g2],[t2]
From (
        Select A.machineID
              ,B.*
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply (
                    Values (concat('g',A.workShift),A.goodCount)
                          ,(concat('t',A.workShift),A.totalCount)
               ) B (Item,Value)
     ) A
 Pivot (sum(Value) For [Item] in ([g1],[t1],[g2],[t2]) ) p
```

Comment: When I replace `YourTable` with `@counts`, the generated SQL works perfectly.  However, when I do the same to the dynamic SQL, I get the error `Must declare the table variable @counts`.  What is happening?

Comment: @MarredCheese No.  Table variables are not visible in Dynamic SQL, Unless they are defined within the dynamic SQL.  You can use temp tables, they are visible.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Thanks for all your help!  It's a tough call, but I'm picking SqlZim's answer just because it's what I'm actually going to use (due to its simplicity).  However, I really appreciate your answer's scalability, so I am upvoting it.

Comment: @MarredCheese Conditional aggregation is always my first choice.  That said, I prefer Pivot for dynamic.  (easier to construct dynamically)